# Find the domain in which a sequence converges

Tags: equation-solving, sequence

I seem to have a lot of problems in the format of:

> Given the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^\alpha+1}{2n^8+5}$, for $\alpha > 0$, find the values of $\alpha$ such that the sequence converges.

However, I can never seem to get *Mathematica* to solve for a variable in a limit.

I have tried

```
Solve[Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions :> a > 0] == 0, a]

Reduce[Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions :> a > 0] == 0, a]
```

`Solve` gave me no solutions, with a warning about inverse function. `Reduce` gave me the solution is `C[1] ∈ Integers && α == 0`, which also violates the initial assumption ($\alpha > 0$). However, I tried particular cases manually, such as

```
Limit[(1 + n^3)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions :> a > 0] == 0
```

which gave `True`. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Hey! The denominator has a `n^8` in it ... Doesn't that whisper something near your left ear?

Comment: @belisarius Yes, I'm aware of the solution to the problem, I was just wondering if it is possible to have mathematica evaluate these types of problems involving limits.

Comment: Expanding the function around $n=\infty$ with `Series` more or less displays the solution.

Comment: @whuber Hmm do you mean you just used: `Series[a[n], {n, Infinity,Infinity}`?

Comment: That expression would take forever.  Stop at order $2$ or so, as in `Series[a[n], {n, Infinity, 2}]`.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, that does pretty much give the answer. But it sounds like there isn't a way to get a nice closed form solution using limit/solve?

Comment: I don't think so, Paul, because *MMA* will not evaluate the limit symbolically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reasons `Limit` does not work well with inequalities in assumptions. To see the problem one can try this :

```
Manipulate[ Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a == h],
            {h, 0, 20}]
```

it does work well unlike :

```
Manipulate[ Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > h],
            {h, 0, 20}]
```

Since the first way works well, one can find easily (also in more sophisticated examples) appropriate values, e.g.

```
Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> #] & /@ { a < 8, a == 8, a > 8}
```

> ```
>  {0, 1/2, Infinity}
> ```

The problem with using `Limit` with `Reduce` is rather of more general nature, e.g. :

```
Reduce[ Limit[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a == h] == 0, h, Reals]
```

> ```
>  False
> ```

This is certainly a bug.

On the other hand `SumConvergence` seems to behave better :

```
Assuming[a ∈ Reals, SumConvergence[(1 + n^a)/(5 + 2 n^8), n]]
```

> ```
>   a < 7
> ```