# Solve with limit over multiple variables

Tags: equation-solving

Very new to Mathematica so apologies for what is probably numpty question. The following returns no solutions. However, there is a solution! If I set a = 1 I get the solution b = 1/2. Can you explain how I'm misusing `Solve`?

```
f[x_] := Log[1/x + 1]^(-1);
Solve[Limit[Abs[f[x] - (x + b)], x -> Infinity] == 0, b]
(* out: {{b -> 1/2}} *)
```

contradicts

```
f[x_] := Log[1/x + 1]^(-1);
Solve[Limit[Abs[f[x] - (a x + b)], x -> Infinity] == 0, {a, b}]
(* out: {} *)
```

Comment: Look at this answer discussing a closely related issue [Find the domain in which a sequence converges](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/find-the-domain-in-which-a-sequence-converges/23049#23049). In fact we encounter the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have value for the limit only when a=1
check this:

```
    Limit[Abs[f[x] - (a x + b)], x -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {a == 1, b \[Element] Reals}]

(*1/2 Abs[1 - 2 b]*)

Limit[Abs[f[x] - (a x + b)], x -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {a != 1, {a, b} \[Element] Reals}]
(*\[Infinity]*)
```

Comment: So why does solve not find this unique solution? It says there is no solution by returning {}

Comment: @kungfujam Have a look At SolveAlways